# Why does iterm2 close new sessions immediately?

Tags: bash, iterm

I've made some changes to my `.bashrc` file in my new MacBook, mainly aliases for common commands.

Shortly after, [iterm2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home) immediately closes every new session or tab with the following cryptic message:

```
## exec failed ##
argpath= error=No such file or directory
```

**Notes:**

- `terminal` works fine.
- I've tried to rename `.bashrc` and relaunch `iterm`, but the problem persists.

Comment: When you say "no luck", do you mean you are unable to rename .bashrc, or that when you do, the problem persists? If it is the second, have you relaunched iTerm2 or rebooted since renaming .bashrc?

Comment: Clarified the question - I meant that the renaming did not help. I will try to reboot now.

Comment: Isn't there a setting you can uncheck to leave the briefly active session open?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default shell was a `command` shell without command, not a `login shell`.

Solution:

<kbd>iTerm</kbd>-><kbd>Preferences</kbd>-><kbd>Profiles</kbd>-><kbd>General</kbd>-><kbd>Command</kbd>

Set radio button to <kbd>Login shell</kbd>

Answer (score 11):

For some others go to iTerm > Preferences > Profiles > General > Command.

If the radio button is ‘Login shell’ change the radio button to ‘Command’ and enter

> /bin/bash -l

Should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: just worked for me on 3.0.12

Comment: nice.. glad I was helpful

Comment: I had an enterprise configured machine which configured shell as `/bin/false`, so setting this fixed the non-startable iTerm. The `-l` helped make sure the start up scripts were loaded as a login.

Answer (score 1):

Given the error message, you are trying to assign some value to the `argpath` variable, but you have a space after the `=` -- no spaces allowed there.